# Eclipse hide action or actionset in Navigate menu

Tags: eclipse, plugins, pde

I am extending an extension point `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` where I am creating element `actionSet` which contains `action` element inside. This asctionset is placed inside Navigate menu of eclipse For example:

```
<actionSet
    label="%CNavigationActionSet.label"
    description="%CNavigationActionSet.description"
    visible="false"
    id="xxx.ui.NavigationActionSet">
        <action
            class="xxx.opentype.OpenTypeAction"
            definitionId="xxx.navigate.opentype"
            helpContextId="xxxui.open_type_action"
            icon="icons/xxx.gif"
            id="xxx.ui.actions.OpenType"
            label="Open Element"
            menubarPath="navigate/open.ext2"
            toolbarPath="org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet/Search"
            tooltip="%OpenTypeAction.tooltip">
         </action>
</actionSet>
```

Now I want to hide this action when certain conditions are met in Eclipse. Is there a way to hide (set visibility to false etc.) of this action in navigate menu?
Right now best what I figured out is to disable action when conditions are met, but this is not enough:

```
public class OpenTypeAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
    //... some code

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
            action.setEnabled(!areConditionsMet());
    }

    //... some code
}
```

*/Edit:* Solution for me would be also to hide whole actionSet instead of action, is that possible?
*/Edit2:* To clarify what my conditions are - my editor can contain files with multiple file extensions, I want to show this action only for files which end with certain file extension.

Comment: action sets don't provide a way to control visibility other than the perspective associations. This is one of the reasons they were deprecated and replaced with the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I will use menu then.